# Why can I use a Java lib from the Scala REPL but not from a script?

Tags: java, scala, classpath

I’m working on a Scala script which uses Joda Time. Up until today, this was working fine. Somehow, something’s changed and it’s no longer working.

This works:

```
$ scala -cp "lib/*"
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_29).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time._

scala> Period.minutes(5)
res0: org.joda.time.Period = PT5M
```

but this doesn’t:

```
$ scala -cp "lib/*" test.scala
/Users/avi/Dev/experiments/rollups/scala/test.scala:4: error: object joda is not a member of package org
import org.joda.time._
           ^
one error found
```

`test.scala` contains only:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala -cp lib/* -deprecation
!#

import org.joda.time._

Period.minutes(5)
```

this also doesn’t work:

```
$ scala -cp "lib/*" -e "import org.joda.time._"
/var/folders/c4/gh5y9_cx5bz8x_4wm060l_mm0000gn/T/scalacmd1248995773392653303.scala:1: error: object joda is not a member of package org
import org.joda.time._
           ^
one error found
```

It’s also not caused by using `*` in the `cp` arg:

```
$ scala -cp lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:lib/joda-convert-1.2.jar -e "import org.joda.time._"
/var/folders/c4/gh5y9_cx5bz8x_4wm060l_mm0000gn/T/scalacmd5438658792813459030.scala:1: error: object joda is not a member of package org
import org.joda.time._
           ^
one error found
```

…It’s just so crazy because this was working last time I worked on this project, just a day or two ago! And now it’s not working, and I guess I must have changed something, but honestly I can’t think of what it might be.

Help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: `fsc`, the “fast compilation daemon”, had a problem with its cache; `fsc -shutdown` resolved the problem.

[Seth Tisue](http://tisue.net/) in [the Scala IRC channel on FreeNode](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/813) was able to help me solve my problem — it had something do with with [`fsc`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/fsc.html) the “fast offline compiler daemon”. When the `scala` command is used to run a script, it uses `fsc`, and it appears that somehow the classpath used/cached by the daemon got messed up.

It turns out there are a few ways to work around this:

- pass the arg `-nocompdaemon` to `scala` to just not use fsc at all

  - works, and should be failproof, but slow
- run `fsc -shutdown`

  - the daemon will be automatically restarted the next time you use `scala`
- run `fsc -reset` to reset the daemon’s caches

  - would probably be faster than shutting it down but the least failproof option

I still don’t know exactly what caused this problem to occur in the first place, but the impression I got from Seth and from the `fsc` page is that this sort of things just happens sometimes.

Thanks, Seth!

Comment: The _best_ way to handle it is not to use relative paths in the classpath directives.

Comment: Thanks @DanielC.Sobral, that makes sense, but this seems impractical for scripts. My script has this at the top: `#!/usr/bin/env scala -cp lib/* -deprecation
!#` and I want to be able to invoke the script from any location in bash. So maybe there’s a better way to do this but it’s not obvious to me, as I’m not a bash expert nor a Scala expert.

Comment: Use the alternative invocation mode -- call sh, and then, from sh, call scala, at which point you can use pwd to get the current directory.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral thanks but I don’t understand — could you illustrate? Thanks!

Comment: `#!/bin/sh`, `exec scala -cp 'pwd'/lib/* "$0" "$@"`, `!#`, each on its own line. And '' around pwd were meant to be backticks, but they are used in wiki formatting.

Comment: Caused me kind of a trouble, but figured out killing a mysterious Java process solved the issue. Now I know the reason :D Thx for the details, guys!