# Running a Scala script outside of its directory with classpath

Tags: scala

So here's a strange thing I came around. Let's say I have a project with a `lib` folder where I have a few jar files and a `src` folder where I have a Scala source file that I would like to run as a script.

When I go to the `src` folder it works perfectly for the following command:

```
scala -cp ../lib/my.jar MyScript.scala
```

However, if I try to execute the script from the project root directory as:

```
scala -cp lib/my.jar src/MyScript.scala
```

It gaves me type errors because it cannot find the *classes within the jar file*. Anyone knows a workaround for running scripts outside of their own directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the exact errors?

Comment: I believe it wouldn't make much sense: I get errors like: `not found value: xxx`, where `xxx` is a package within `my.jar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, it seems that I encountered some very strange constellation here.

Actually, I was using CygWin under Windows. I found that a `java` process started when I first compiled which hasn't terminated. I killed it, then tried it again and it worked (probably it cached some classes?).

## Update

Haha, I found a very similar issue in SO. Their conclusion was similar to mine, so if you're interested in the details, [check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691769/why-can-i-use-a-java-lib-from-the-scala-repl-but-not-from-a-script). Bummer, it was kinda hard to find...